# How to make jpeg lossless in java?

Tags: java, jpeg, lossless-compression, lossless

Is there someone that can tell me how to write 'jpeg' file using `lossless` compression in java?

I read the bytes using the code below to edit the bytes

```
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
```

And I need to write again the bytes as 'jpeg' file without compressing in `lossy`.

Comment: I'm not expert in image processing and compression, but as far as I know, for general usage, [hufmman code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is optimal for lossless compression

Comment: JPEG is a lossy encoding. If you want lossless then you should use a different image format.

Comment: @Cameron: there are lossless variants of JPEG

Answer (score 8):

The JAI package offers the ability to save “lossless JPEG” formats. Set compresion type to [JPEG-LS or JPEG-LOSSLESS](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/javadoc/1.1/overview-summary.html#JPEG) depending on what variant you want.

I'm not sure you *really* want lossless-JPEG though. It's a separate format that's not really much to do with the normal JPEG format. It is not, in general, very well-supported; for lossless image storage you are typically better off with something like PNG.

If you need to do lossless image transcoding (ie the set of cropping and rotation operations you can do without disturbing the boundaries of the DCT matrices), you would generally do it with the `jpegtran` command, as there's not currently a Java binding to the IJG library as far as I know.

ETA:

> do you know how to do it with JAI.

I've not tried it myself (code below is untested), but it should be a straightforward call to `setCompressionType`. (Of course ‘straightforward’ in Java still means negotiating a maze of twisty little objects to set what would be a simple switch anywhere else:)

```
ImageWriter writer= (ImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
ImageWriteParam param= writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(param.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LS");
writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File(path)));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

JPEG-LS is the newer lossless JPEG standard. It compresses more than the original JPEG-LOSSLESS standard but support is even worse. Most applications that support JPEG will not be able to do anything with these.

Comment: do you know how to do it with JAI.. i can't find any idea on google.. there's no sample code..

Comment: I will use it in steganography.

Comment: ImageWriter is not from JAI. it's just from javax.imageio and   error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown compression type! from line >> param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LS");

Comment: I believe installing JAI adds new compression types to the standard ImageIO.