# How to convert PNG to JPEG losslessly?

Tags: python, java, png, jpeg, imagemagick-convert

I've converted PNG to JPEG with both java and python PIL.
Python code :

```
from PIL import Image  

img = Image.open('input.png')
img.save('output.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=100)
```

For converting the Java code I used:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class PngToJpeg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Specify the input and output file paths
        String inputFile = "./test.png";
        String outputFile = "./testout.jpg";

        // Read the input image into a BufferedImage
        BufferedImage inputImage = null;
        try {
            inputImage = ImageIO.read(new File(inputFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Write the input image to the output file as a JPEG image
        try {
            ImageIO.write(inputImage, "jpg", new File(outputFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

below code shows me the exact value of each pixel:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("test.jpeg")
pixellist = list(img.getdata())
print(pixellist)
```

When I convert JPEG to PNG with both Python and JAVA the pixel values are exactly the same. But when its the other way around it seems like there were 2 or 3 subtracted from many pixels.
For example:

JPEG pixels(after conversion):
`(22, 22, 22), (219, 219, 219), (219, 219, 219), (219, 219, 219), (219, 219, 219)`

PNG pixels(original image):
`(22, 22, 22), (222, 222, 222), (222, 222, 222), (222, 222, 222), (222, 222, 222)`

Things to note here that the PNG has no ALPHA channel.

So what am i missing here? How to achieve the exact same pixel values when converting a PNG to JPEG?

I have also checked imagemagick, convert. They appear to be the same result.

Comment: Where is the conversion code? Are you sure you're converting to lossless JPEG?

Comment: Did you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7619091/3558960)?

Comment: Lossless JPEG? That seems like an oxymoron. Why/what?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG , JPEG-LS is an extension to JPEG that adds lossless compression. But it's not the same thing as JPEG with quality set to 100%.

Comment: @ChiaraCoetzee *The standard Independent JPEG Group libraries cannot encode or decode it* I guess that's why I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, JPEG is a lossy compression format at all quality levels. It doesn't matter if you set the quality to 100%. See [this earlier question "Is JPEG lossless when quality is set to 100?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982409/is-jpeg-lossless-when-quality-is-set-to-100). There are extensions such as [JPEG-LS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) that are lossless, but it is a totally different compression algorithm with its own file extension (.jls) and container, and most mainstream software cannot decode it. If you need lossless, here are some options:

1. Keep it in PNG. If you're really concerned about PNG filesize, you can recompress with [pngcrush](https://pmt.sourceforge.io/pngcrush/), [OptiPNG](https://optipng.sourceforge.net/), or [AdvancedCOMP](http://www.advancemame.it/comp-readme).
2. Use [WebP in lossless mode](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/gallery2). Supported by most modern browsers and often smaller filesize than PNG. Here is a [guide to writing WebP images in Java](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/how-to-write-webp-images-in-java-with-jdeli/) using ImageIO or JDeli (if you use JDeli, you can call [SetCompressionFormat](https://files.idrsolutions.com/maven/site/jdeli/apidocs/com/idrsolutions/image/webp/options/WebpEncoderOptions.html#setCompressionFormat(com.idrsolutions.image.webp.options.WebpCompressionFormat)) to select lossless). In Python, you can use [Pillow's WebP support](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp) and pass `lossless=True` to `save()`.
3. Use AVIF (AV1 image format) in lossless mode. (Supported by recent versions of Chrome and Firefox.)
4. Use JPEG-LS, JPEG 2000 in lossless mode, or JPEG XL in lossless mode. (JPEG XL support can be enabled in [certain recent web browser versions](https://caniuse.com/jpegxl).)

[This article](https://siipo.la/blog/whats-the-best-lossless-image-format-comparing-png-webp-avif-and-jpeg-xl) does a basic comparison of them, and [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AV1/comments/aabqdc/lossless_compression_test_png_vs_webp_vs_avif/) does a more thorough comparison. Overall, I'd say that WebP offers the best balance of wide software support and high compression ratios.